# martingale central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $(X_{n},\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a martingale with $\sigma_n:= \|{X_n}\|_2<\infty$, and $\Delta_n=X_n-X_{n-1}$. Under the following assumptions

(i) $\sigma_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$,
(ii) for any $\varepsilon >0$,
$\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left( \Delta_i^2\mathbb{1}_{\{|\Delta_i| \ge \varepsilon \sigma_n \}}\right) \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty$ .
(iii) Define $G_n^2:= \sum_{i=1}^n E(\Delta_i^{2}\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1})$, we have $ \sigma_n^{-2}G_n^2\to 1$ in Prob as $n\to\infty$.
(iv) $\sup_n\sigma_n^{-2}G_n^2\le a<\infty$ a.s.

Show that
$
\frac{X_n}{\sigma_n}\Rightarrow \text{N}(0,1)\text{ as } n\to\infty. $

I got a hint that using Lindeberg technique to prove $E\exp(i t \sigma_n^{-1}X_n + \frac12\sigma_n^{-2}G_n^2t^2) \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

Is this one type of martingale CLT? How I can prove it under the assumption (i)-(iv)?

Comment: Yes,this is commonly called a martingale central limit theorem. In order to prove the convergence $E\exp(i t \sigma_n^{-1}X_n + \frac12\sigma_n^{-2}G_n^2t^2)$, we usually use Taylor's formula for the exponential and we have to control the contribution of the remainder.

Comment: Hi @DavideGiraudo, Could you please provides some details to prove that ? Or is there any reference about this kind of martingale CLT? Thank you!

Comment: Can I use the Lindeberg arrays to solve the problem?